# Producing a histogram in Matlab with out using Hist

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am using histograms in Matlab to look at the distribution of some data from my experiments. I want to find the mean distribution (mean height of the bars) from a group of tests then produce an average histogram.

By using this code:

```
data = zeros(26,31);

for i = 1:length(files6)
    x = csvread(files6(i).name);
    
    x = x(1:end,:);
    time = x(:,1);
    variable = x(:,3);
    
    thing(:,1) = x(:,1);
    thing(:,2) = x(:,3);
    figure()
    binCenter = {0:tbinstep:tbinend 0:varbinstep:varbinend};
    hist3(thing, 'Ctrs', binCenter, 'CDataMode','auto','FaceColor','interp');
    colorbar
    
    [N,C] = hist3(thing, 'Ctrs', binCenter);
    data = data + N;
    
    clearvars x time variable
end
    
avedata = data / i;
```

I can find the mean of N, which will be the Z value for the plot (histogram) I want, and I have X,Y (which are the same for all tests) from:

```
x = 0:tbinstep:tbinend;
y = 0:varbinstep:varbinend;
```

But how do I bring these together to make the graphical out that shows the average height of the bars? I can't use hist3 again as that will just calculate the distribution of avedata.

**AT THE RISK OF STARTING AN XY PROBLEM** using bar3 has been suggested, but that asks the question "how do I go from 2 vectors and a matrix to 1 matrix bar3 can handle? I.e. how do I plot x(1), y(1), avedata(1,1) and so on for all the data points in avedata?"

TIA

Comment: Can we say that you are trying a find a way to plot the output of Matlab's `hist3` function, here `N,C`, like it does without calling this function ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, that explains it so much better.

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it's doing exactly the same as `hist3` function does.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at `hist3` source code in matlab r2014b, it has his own plotting implemented inside that prepares data and plot it using `surf` method. Here is a function that reproduce the same output highly inspired from the `hist3` function with your options (`'CDataMode','auto','FaceColor','interp'`). You can put this in a new file called `hist3plot.m`:

```
function [ h ] = hist3plot( N, C )
%HIST3PLOT Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

xBins = C{1};
yBins = C{2};

% Computing edges and width
nbins = [length(xBins), length(yBins)];
xEdges = [0.5*(3*xBins(1)-xBins(2)), 0.5*(xBins(2:end)+xBins(1:end-1)), 0.5*(3*xBins(end)-xBins(end-1))];
yEdges = [0.5*(3*yBins(1)-yBins(2)), 0.5*(yBins(2:end)+yBins(1:end-1)), 0.5*(3*yBins(end)-yBins(end-1))];
xWidth = xEdges(2:end)-xEdges(1:end-1);
yWidth = yEdges(2:end)-yEdges(1:end-1);
del = .001; % space between bars, relative to bar size
% Build x-coords for the eight corners of each bar.
xx = xEdges;
xx = [xx(1:nbins(1))+del*xWidth; xx(2:nbins(1)+1)-del*xWidth];
xx = [reshape(repmat(xx(:)',2,1),4,nbins(1)); NaN(1,nbins(1))];
xx = [repmat(xx(:),1,4) NaN(5*nbins(1),1)];
xx = repmat(xx,1,nbins(2));
% Build y-coords for the eight corners of each bar.
yy = yEdges;
yy = [yy(1:nbins(2))+del*yWidth; yy(2:nbins(2)+1)-del*yWidth];
yy = [reshape(repmat(yy(:)',2,1),4,nbins(2)); NaN(1,nbins(2))];
yy = [repmat(yy(:),1,4) NaN(5*nbins(2),1)];
yy = repmat(yy',nbins(1),1);
% Build z-coords for the eight corners of each bar.
zz = zeros(5*nbins(1), 5*nbins(2));
zz(5*(1:nbins(1))-3, 5*(1:nbins(2))-3) = N;
zz(5*(1:nbins(1))-3, 5*(1:nbins(2))-2) = N;
zz(5*(1:nbins(1))-2, 5*(1:nbins(2))-3) = N;
zz(5*(1:nbins(1))-2, 5*(1:nbins(2))-2) = N;
% Plot the bars in a light steel blue.
cc = repmat(cat(3,.75,.85,.95), [size(zz) 1]);
% Plot the surface
h = surf(xx, yy, zz, cc, 'CDataMode','auto','FaceColor','interp');
% Setting x-axis and y-axis limits
xlim([yBins(1)-yWidth(1) yBins(end)+yWidth(end)]) % x-axis limit
ylim([xBins(1)-xWidth(1) xBins(end)+xWidth(end)]) % y-axis limit

end
```

You can then call this function when you want to plot outputs from Matlab's `hist3` function. Note that this can handle non uniform positionning of bins:

```
close all; clear all;

data = rand(10000,2);
xBins = [0,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,1];
yBins = [0,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,1];

figure()
hist3(data, {xBins yBins}, 'CDataMode','auto','FaceColor','interp')
title('Using hist3')

figure()
[N,C] = hist3(data, {xBins yBins});
hist3plot(N, C); % The function is called here
title('Using hist3plot')
```

Here is a comparison of the two outputs:

[image: using hist3 function]
[image: using hist3plot function]

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question and code correctly, you are plotting the distribution of multiple experiments' data as histograms, then you want to *calculate the average shape of all the previous histograms.*

I usually avoid giving approaches the asker isn't explicitly asking for, but for this one I must comment that *it is a very strange thing to do.* I've never heard of calculating the average shape of multiple histograms before. *So just in case*, you could simply append all your experiment's data into a single variable, and plot a normalized histogram of that using [`histogram2`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram2.html). This code outputs a [relative frequency histogram](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-relative-frequency-histogram-3126360). [(Other normalization methods](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram2-properties.html#buvhqe4-Normalization))

```
% Append all data in a single matrix
x = []
for i = 1:length(files6)
    x = [x; csvread(files6(i).name)];
end

% Plot normalized bivariate histogram, normalized
xEdges = 0:tbinstep:tbinend;
yEdges = 0:varbinstep:varbinend;
histogram2(x(:,1), x(:,3), xEdges, yEdges, 'Normalize', 'Probability')
```

---

Now, if you really are looking to draw the average shape of multiple histograms, then yes, use [`bar3`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html). Since `bar3` doesn't accept an (x,y) value argument, you can follow the other answer, or modify the `XTickLabel` and `YTickLabel` property to match whatever your bin range is, afterwards.

```
... % data = yourAverageData;

% Save axis handle to `h`
h = bar3(data);

% Set property of axis
h.XTickLabels = 0:tbinstep:tbinend;
h.YTickLabels = 0:varbinstep:varbinend;
```

Comment: "it is a very strange thing to do" - that's cutting edge research for you ;)